# How to retrieve data based on specific field in Django Rest Framework using RetrieveAPIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

With the code below, I am able to retrieve data based on `id`, how can I update this code so I can retrieve data based on fileName instead?

My urls is

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("items/<pk>", SingleUploadItem.as_view()),
]
```

My views is:

```
class SingleUploadItem(RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer
```

My model is

```
class fileUpload(models.Model):
    fileName = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What is the name of the `fileupload` serializer class?

Comment: FileUploadSerializer @David Lu

Comment: `fileUploadSerializer` or `FileUploadSerializer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("items/<str:file_name>", SingleUploadItem.as_view()),
]
```

And in views.py,

```
from rest_framework import status
from .models import fileUpload
from .serializers import FileUploadSerializer

class SingleUploadItem(RetrieveAPIView):

    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer

    def get(self, request, file_name):
        try:
            fileupload_obj = fileUpload.objects.get(fileName = file_name)
            return Response(FileUploadSerializer(fileupload_obj).data)
        except fileUpload.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```